# Python: why the code for swapping the largest and the smallest numbers isn't working?

Tags: python, list

Imagine we have a list of numbers `a` where all numbers are different, and we want to swap the largest one and the smallest one. The question is, why this code in Python:

```
a[a.index(min(a))], a[a.index(max(a))] = a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]
```

isn't working?

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: Nothing actually. No changes in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why does it fail? Let's take `a = [1, 2, 3, 4]` as example.

First, the right side is evaluated:

```
a[a.index(max(a))], a[a.index(min(a))]    =>    4, 1
```

That's btw of course the same as

```
max(a), min(a)    =>    4, 1
```

Next, the assignments happen, [from left to right](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements):

First, setting `a[a.index(min(a))]` to 4 makes the list `[4, 2, 3, 4]`, as the minimum is at the front.

Then, setting `a[a.index(max(a))]` to 1 makes the list `[1, 2, 3, 4]` again, as the maximum has been written at the front, so that's where it is found now and where the 1 gets written.

Comment: Great answer!! Knew it was something like this, but was searching for some time :P

Answer (score 4):

Better to get index of max and min first:

```
i_min, i_max = a.index(min(a)), a.index(max(a))
a[i_min], a[i_max] = a[i_max], a[i_min]
```

Other way result can be unpredictable)